# PHP Show Products within the child categories... custom shopping cart

Tags: php, sql, search, while-loop

I have a shopping cart im making. And I'm stumped at finding out how I can load products within multi-level categories that are children of the category im looking at.

For example:
-Cars
Subarus (Legacy, Outback) - Holden (Commodore, Calais) - Toyota (Corolla, Camry)

If i'm looking in the cars category, i can select the child category but I cant view the actual products that are in those sub-categories. Is there any way I can do this? even if you can have unlimited levels of categories like "ROOT > Cars > Sedan > Subaru's..."?

---

Each product has a category ID which it relates to a category. Each category has its unique ID and a 'parent' id which has the ID of the category that it's a child of.

Comment: Tables structures and relationships could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you'll need to do is build up a list of category IDs to then construct an `IN` clause for your sql. Let's say you have the following category structure:

- Cars (id:1)

  - Toyota (id:2, parent:1)

    - Mini (id:3, parent:2)
    - Corolla (id:4, parent:3)
  - Holden (id:5, parent:1)

    - Sports (id:6, parent:5)
    - HSV (id:7, parent:6)

To get all descendants of a category, you'll need to loop through the parent/child structure with something like this:

```
/** 
  * I'm only writing pseudocode here btw; I haven't tested it.
  * Obviously you'll need to fire the SQL commands...
  */
function getKids ($id, $found = array()) 
{
  array_push ($found, $id);
  $nbrKids = "select count(id) from category where parent_id = $id";
  if ($nbrKids > 0) {
    $newKids = "select id from category where parent_id = $id";
    foreach ($newKids as $kid) {
      return getKids ($kid, $found);
    }
  }
  else {
    return $found;
  }
}
```

Then call `getKids()` like this, where `$id` is your category id:

```
$ids = getKids($id);
```

`$ids` is an array of all the categories you are interested in. You could then use `join()` to construct an SQL string:

```
$sql = "select * from cars where category_id in (" . join (",", $ids) . ")";
```

For correctness, you should check that `$ids` has at least 1 member first, otherwise your SQL query will be invalid.

[edit: actually in the above code, `$ids` will always have at least one member: the initial id. However, the code doesn't verify the initial id is a valid category_id. ]

Comment: Thank you so much :) Thats great... i'll have a go!